# Jquery Random Math without repeating previous var

Tags: jquery, math, random

I have the following code

```
var link = [];
link[0] = "css/pink/pink.css";
link[1] = "css/blue/blue.css";
link[3] = "";   
function changeStyle() {
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * link.length );
    var style = link[ran];
    jQuery('link[id=style-switch]').attr({href : style});
}
```

It works, although I am unsure as to how to make it not repeat a previous choice until they have all been looped through. Any ideas?

Comment: I would simply loop thru 1 by 1 instead of trying to random.

Comment: `Math.random()` is javascript, not jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shuffle of your array (basically a random permutation of the array elements) - this would require keeping a separate, shuffled array though and an index into it. Here's an example for a [Fisher-Yates shuffle in Javascript](http://sedition.com/perl/javascript-fy.html).

Comment: Ai yi yi, this is a tad complicated, wouldn't you say? All the OP needs to do is hang on to the previously chosen random values and make sure the random value he just chose isn't in that array.

Comment: Too many long words. :( But really, this is a simple issue. There's no need to keep a shuffled array and an index to that when all you need is one other array, particularly because there are so few possibilities here. Speed isn't an issue.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: It's not that easy - your "simplified" algorithm might theoretically never stop, e.g. imagine an array of 1 million elements of which you have used all but one - it will take a very long time with your approach until you chose that element. Fisher Yates shuffle is a well proven algorithm to produce a random permutation of the input array which is *exactly* what OP needs

Comment: Worse, it will lead to an infinite loop if it's called too many times.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Thing is, the OP only has four elements, possibly five or *maybe* even six.

Comment: It's a bit more complex if the OP wants to loop round his elements several times with a different order each time, but still never repeating an element.